# Generate unpredictable/unforgeable URL from predictable ID

Tags: rest, security, url, uniqueidentifier

I have a simple API that return Something for a given ID and it must be used without any kind of authentication, the URL should be permanent and yet I want to avoid as much as possible it to be botted.
The Url is something like this:
`https://url/{SomeId}/doSomething`

The problem is that this is very predicable and a bot could easily try all the ID and get everything associated to it.
I'm looking for a way to make the URL non predictable like for example:
`https://url/{SomeId}/doSomething?Key=SomeVeryLongCryptographicKey`
In this way except if you run a supercalculator you shouldn't be able to deduce all the URLs

I know that there is probably a lot of ways to do that, like using a DB which I want to avoid.
I guess I'm looking for a kind a JWT associated to the ID without expiration but maybe there is better solution.

Edit: to give a better example i'm looking to do a bit like did Zoom for permanent invitation Links. They had predictable room Ids and they added a password making it unpredictable lie so:

```
https://us05web.zoom.us/j/132465789?pwd=SUxIU0pLankyhTRtWmlGbFlNZ21Ndz08
```

What would be the best/light/"secure" way to achieve that ?
Also I'm using .Net if there is a library doing that, it would be great.

Comment: Why not ditch {SomeId} altogether and use a hash there?

Comment: Because it would necessitate to have a table to associate Hash to it's original ID (that I have to deal with), and if possible i would prefer to avoid that

Answer (score 1):

I think your idea of using a JWT makes the most sense. Better to use something standard from a cryptographic point of view, and the JSON format allows for encoding whatever you need to provide to the receiving endpoint (user names, entity names, entity IDs, other things).

There are standard Microsoft libraries for building and validating JWTs, but I prefer the library Jwt.Net (https://www.nuget.org/packages/JWT). It lets you do something like this quite easily:

```
var token = JwtBuilder()
            .WithAlgorithm(new RS256Algorithm(publicKey,privateKey))
            .AddClaim("uri", String.Format("https://example.com/api/{0}/{1}", entityName, entityId))
            .Encode();
```

Just add whatever claims you like, and the JWT will then contain what you want to transfer (I've used an example of the URI that you want to give to the entity) and a signature with your private key. You could even just give a URL like `https://example.com/from_token/eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1cmkiOiJodHRwczovL2V4YW1wbGUuY29tL2FwaS90ZXN0RW50aXR5LzEyMzQifQ.K2P4wSF6g1Kt-IHMzlklWTV09_MIkoiNHQztSIYOohmOWe7aBfFSQLIKSbdTECj9XPjNNG_AjH9fdjFglkPuYfr2G9rtl2eh5vTjwdM-Uc0X6RkBu0Z2j7KyMKjkaI3zfkIwhtL1mH873xEBtNOGOW18fuBpgnm8zhMAj1oD3PlDW8-fYBrfLb6VK97DGh_DyxapbksgUeHst7cAGg3Nz97InDPtYcWDi6lDuVQsj3t4iaJBRL8IM785Q8xjlHHhzdfcX3xU4IhflyNHHXxP56_8ahNNMOZKWdwgbTSIxEEB98b3naY3XknC-ea7Nc1y4_5fszrYdy3LaQWV43jpaA`
and have the handler decode the entity name and ID you want to retrieve directly from the URI while verifying the signature. Decoding with the library is just as easy:

```
var json = JwtBuilder.Create()
                     .WithAlgorithm(new RS256Algorithm(_key))
                     .MustVerifySignature()
                     .Decode(token);
```